# Spider not scraping the right amount of items

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been learning Scrapy for the past couple of days, and I am having trouble with getting all the list elements on the page.

So the page has a similar structure like this:

```
<ol class="list-results">
    <li class="SomeClass i">
        <ul>
            <li class="name">Name1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="SomeClass 0">
        <ul>
            <li class="name">Name2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="SomeClass i">
        <ul>
            <li class="name">Name3/li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

In the Parse function of Scrapy, I get all the list elements like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        all_elements = sel.css('.SomeClass')
        print len(all_elemts)
```

I know that there are **about 300 list elements with that class** on the test page that I request, however after printing the len(all_elements), I am getting only **61**.

I have tried using xpaths like:

```
sel.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'SomeClass')]")
```

And yet still I am getting like 61 elements instead of the 300 that I should be.

Also I am using a **try and except claws** in case one element was to give me an exception.

Here is the actual page I would be scraping:
https://search.msu.edu/people/index.php?fst=ab&lst=&nid=&filter=

Please understand, I am doing this for practice only!

Please Help!Thank You! I just don't know what else to do!

Comment: Please show us the page you are scraping.

Comment: @MathiasMüller here is the page that I would be scraping: https://search.msu.edu/people/index.php?fst=ab&lst=&nid=&filter=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you are dealing with *a non well-formed and broken HTML* which Scrapy (and underlying `lxml`) is not able to parse reliably. For instance, see this unclosed `div` inside the `li` tag:

```
<li class="unit"><span>Unit:</span> 
    <div class="unit-block"> Language Program                  
</li>
```

I'd switch to parsing the HTML manually with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). In other words, continue to use all other parts and components of the Scrapy framework, but the HTML-parsing part leave to `BeautifulSoup`.

Demo from the [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell "https://search.msu.edu/people/index.php?fst=ab&lst=&nid=&filter="
In [1]: len(response.css('li.student'))
Out[1]: 55

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)

In [4]: len(soup.select('li.student'))
Out[4]: 281
```

If you are using a `CrawlSpider` and need a `LinkExtractor` based on `BeautifulSoup`, see:

- [A scrapy link extractor that uses BeautifulSoup](https://gist.github.com/turian/3261149)

Comment: Thank You for very much for catching that!I have been trying to figure out what is wring for too long.